# How to add semicolon after a single-quote in a PostgreSQL string?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, datetime, special-characters

I'm unable to create a string in PostgreSQL with semicolon after a single quote. 
eg. I need to create a string like:

```
Delhi is India's capital; It's a beautiful state
```

How do I create such a string?

I tried the following:

```
select 'Delhi is India\'s capital; It\'s a beautiful state'
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
Invalid operation: unterminated quoted string at or near "'Delhi is India\'s capital" 
Position: 8;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL, you don't escape single quotes with a backslash, but by doubling them. The semicolon doesn't need a escaping.

So you should use

```
SELECT 'Delhi is India''s capital; It''s a beautiful state';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Dollar-Quoted String Constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

```
knayak=# select $$Delhi is India's capital; It's a beautiful state$$  as s;
                        s
--------------------------------------------------
 Delhi is India's capital; It's a beautiful state
(1 row)
```